# How to use an SQL query with join on the result of another SQL query executed before?

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, join

I am trying to use an SQL query on the result of a previous SQL query but I'm not able to.
I am creating a python script and using postgresql.
I have 3 tables from which I need to match different columns and join the data but using only 2 tables at a time.

For example:
I have table1 where I have a codecolumn and there is a same column of codes in table2
Now I am matching the values of both the columns and joining a column 'area' from table 2  which corresponds to codes and a column 'pincode' from table1.

For this I used the following query which is working:

```
'''
select 
table1.code,table2.code,table2.area,table1.pincode 
from 
table1 left join table2
 ON 
table1.code=table2.code  
order by table1.row_num '''
```

I am getting the result but in this data there is some data in which the area value is returned as None
Wherever I am getting the area as None when matching code columns, I need to use the pincode column in table1 and pincode column in table3 to again find the corresponding area from table3.area.

So I used the following Query:

```
'''
select 
table1.code,table3.area,table1.pincode 
from 
table1 left join table3 
ON 
table1.pincode=table3.pincode 
IN (
select 
table1.code,table2.code,table2.area,table1.pincode 
from 
table1 left join table2
ON 
table1.code=table2.code  
where table2.area is NULL
order by table1.row_num '''
```

and I got the following error:

`sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) subquery has too many columns`

My python code is as follows:

```
import psycopg2
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine=create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://credentials')
conn=engine.connect()

query = '''
select 
table1.code,table2.code,table2.area,table1.pincode 
from 
table1 left join table2
 ON 
table1.code=table2.code  
order by table1.row_num '''

area=conn.execute(query)
area_x=area.fetchall()
for i in area_x:
    print(i)

query2 = select 
table1.code,table3.area,table1.pincode 
from 
table1 left join table3 
ON 
table1.pincode=table3.pincode 
IN (
select 
table1.code,table2.code,table2.area,table1.pincode 
from 
table1 left join table2
 ON 
table1.code=table2.code  
where table2.area is NULL
order by table1.row_num '''  

area=conn.execute(query2)
area_x=area.fetchall()
for i in area_x:
    print(i)
```

This is how my first query is returning the data:

[image]

Wherever I am not able to match the code columns I get None value in area column from table 2 and whenever the area value is None I have to apply another query to find this data
Now i have to match data in table1.pincode with data in table3.pincode to find table3.area and replace the None value with table3.area

These are the 2 ways to find the area

The desired result should be:

[image]

What could be the correct solution??
Thank You

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Hi. I've added some more information to explain. I hope it helps.Thanks @GordonLinoff

Comment: Your additional information is the results desired. While this is good it is pretty useless without the input and table definitions used to generate it. Please add the table definitions and test data, as text - **no images** (see [Why no Images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)) or better create a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/).

Answer (score 0):

it looks that your query2 needs a where clause and the subquery, as per error message should be reduced to the column you are trying to pass to the outer query. query2 should be something like this:

```
query2 = 
select 
table1.code,table3.area,table1.pincode 
from 
table1 left join table3 
ON 
table1.pincode=table3.pincode 
WHERE table1.code
IN (
select 
table1.code
from 
table1 left join table2
 ON 
table1.code=table2.code  
where table2.area is NULL
```

Comment: Hi , The query worked but I did not get the desired result. Maybe my query is not correct for the result I desired. @Jayvee